# Hide internal bibkeys in pdf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref

When I open the pdf generated by `pdflatex` in e.g. firefox, the URL when hovering over a reference shows the internal bibkey. How can I prevent this?

Consider the following MWE:

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 

Test\cite{secretbibkey}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

bib.bib

```
@article{secretbibkey,
    author = {Joe},
    title = {Just a title},
    number = {ABCD-E/2008/ab/1234},
    institution = {University},
    year = {2008}
}
```

Now look at the following screenshot:
[image: Screenshot showing you can see the internally used bibkey]
It shows the bibkey I used when hovering over the citation (apparently the screenshot does not include my cursor but it was above the green "1"). Is there any way to randomize/anonymize these URL-keys?

Comment: that is the destination name which links the cite to the bibliography. I doubt that it would be easy to change this without a lot of internal code changes. Why are you putting something secret in the entry key?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's not really secret but I do not want to offer the insights in my internal workflow / do not want people to see the internal naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. I'm not sure if `\int_to_alpha` handles all chars and input that can appear in a destination, and if it can lead to identical destinations, but it was the best expandable function I found for now. It will scramble all destinations, also the one to sections and labels. To scramble only bib-keys would require a number of changes to the `biblatex` code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \pix_scrample_dest:n #1 {\int_eval:n{\int_from_alph:n{#1} + 2}} %2= secret number 
\def\HyperDestNameFilter#1{\exp_args:Ne\tl_map_function:nN {#1}\pix_scrample_dest:n}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test\cite{secretbibkey}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide all internal labelling, Ulrike's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560287/35864) is much nicer, but here is a way to obfuscate only the links created by `biblatex` via MD5 hashes (I believe MD5 hashes are no longer recommended for anything security critical any more, but it might be enough for your purposes).

The command `\blx@mdfivesum` used here requires a relatively recent `biblatex` version. If you are stuck with an old `biblatex`, load `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` yourself and say `\let\blx@mdfivesum\pdf@mdfivesum`.

The idea is to change all link commands from using the entry key to a hashed version of the entry key.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \protected\def\blx@anchor{%
    \xifinlist{\the\c@refsection @\blx@mdfivesum{\abx@field@entrykey}}{\blx@anchors}
      {}
      {\listxadd\blx@anchors{\the\c@refsection @\blx@mdfivesum{\abx@field@entrykey}}%
       \hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection @\blx@mdfivesum{\abx@field@entrykey}}{}}}%
  \ifundef\hyper@natanchorstart
    {\long\def\blx@bibhyperref[#1]#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyperlink{cite.\the\c@refsection @\blx@mdfivesum{#1}}{\blx@sfrest
         #2%
       \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyperlink{cite.\the\c@refsection:\blx@mdfivesum{#1}}{\blx@sfrest
         #2%
       \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection:\blx@mdfivesum{#1}}{\blx@sfrest
         #2%
       \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}}%
    {\long\def\blx@bibhyperref[#1]#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection @\blx@mdfivesum{#1}}\blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection:\blx@mdfivesum{#1}}\blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natanchorstart{\the\c@refsection:\blx@mdfivesum{#1}}\blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natanchorend\blx@sfrest}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the PDF with obfuscated link.]

---

In case you prefer a numeric designator (which unlike the hash above is not derived from the entry key at all) use the following

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{blx@refnocount}

\newcommand*{\blx@getrefnocount}[1]{%
  \xifinlistcs{#1}{blx@refcounts@\the\c@refsection}
    {}
    {\stepcounter{blx@refnocount}%
     \csnumgdef{blx@refcount@\the\c@refsection @#1}{\value{blx@refnocount}}%
     \listcsxadd{blx@refcounts@\the\c@refsection}{#1}}%
  \letcs\blx@thisrefcount{blx@refcount@\the\c@refsection @#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifundef\hyper@natanchorstart
    {\protected\def\blx@anchor{%
       \xifinlist{\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrykey}{\blx@anchors}
         {}
         {\listxadd\blx@anchors{\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrykey}%
          \blx@getrefnocount{\abx@field@entrykey}%
          \hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection @blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}{}}}%
     \long\def\blx@bibhyperref[#1]#2{%
       \blx@getrefnocount{#1}%
       \blx@sfsave
       \hyperlink{cite.\the\c@refsection @blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}
         {\blx@sfrest
          #2%
          \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
       \blx@getrefnocount{#1}%
       \blx@sfsave
       \hyperlink{cite.\the\c@refsection:blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}
         {\blx@sfrest
          #2%
          \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
       \blx@getrefnocount{#1}%
       \blx@sfsave
       \hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection:blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}
         {\blx@sfrest
          #2%
         \blx@sfsave}\blx@sfrest}}%
    {\protected\def\blx@anchor{%
       \xifinlist{\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrykey}{\blx@anchors}
         {}
         {\listxadd\blx@anchors{\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrykey}%
          \blx@getrefnocount{\abx@field@entrykey}%
          \hyper@natanchorstart{\the\c@refsection @blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}%
          \hyper@natanchorend}}%
     \long\def\blx@bibhyperref[#1]#2{%
       \blx@getrefnocount{#1}%
       \blx@sfsave
       \hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection @blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}%
       \blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
       \blx@getrefnocount{#1}%
       \blx@sfsave
       \hyper@natlinkstart{\the\c@refsection:blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}%
       \blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natlinkend\blx@sfrest}%
     \protected\long\def\blx@imc@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
       \blx@getrefnocount{#1}%
       \blx@sfsave
       \hyper@natanchorstart{\the\c@refsection:blxlinkno\blx@thisrefcount}%
       \blx@sfrest
       #2%
       \blx@sfsave\hyper@natanchorend\blx@sfrest}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography

\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can post-process the created pdf with some command-line tools to search for cite keys and replace them in the pdf source.

First you need to uncompress the pdf to allow textual search and replace, for example with `pdftk`.

In the uncompressed pdf the links look like this:

```
3 0 obj 
<<
/Border [0 0 1]
/Subtype /Link
/H /I
/Type /Annot
/C [0 1 0]
/Rect [169.08 653.748 176.054 665.704]
/A 
<<
/D (cite.0@secretbibkey)
/S /GoTo
>>
>>
endobj
```

and the corresponding parts further down:

```
34 0 obj 
<<
/Names [(Doc-Start) 22 0 R (cite.0@secretbibkey) 21 0 R (page.1) 14 0 R (section*.1) 18 0 R]
/Limits [(Doc-Start) (section*.1)]
>>
endobj
```

Now you can `grep` the source for the pattern `/D (cite.0@[some key])` and store only the key part.

Then, looping over all keys, you can generate a replacement key, for example the `md5` checksum (which can reasonably be expected to be unique for each key).

Next you can replace all occurrences of the key with the replacement using `sed`.

At the end of the loop you re-compress the pdf with `pdftk` and you are done.

Full script (call with `bash myscript.sh mypdf.pdf`):

```bash
pdftk $1 output "raw$1" uncompress
grep -aoP "\/D \(\Kcite.0@[^\)]+(?=\))" "raw$1" | while read -r line ; do
   echo $line
   citehash=`echo $line|md5sum|awk '{ print $1 }'`
   sed -i "s/$line/$citehash/g" "raw$1"
done
pdftk "raw$1" output $1 compress
```

Resulting link tooltip in Firefox:

[image]

Added bonus: the link still works.