# Hyperref adds citation key as meta data to PDF

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, hyperref, metadata, privacy

If I use pdfTeX (v3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23) on Windows (MiKTeX 21.8), Biber 2.16, and the hyperref package, the citation key is printed in the PDF file as meta data.
For example, compiling the document below, I obtain the following line if I open the PDF file with a text editor:

`/A << /S /GoTo /D (cite.0@personA) >>`

Without hyperref, the citation key is not added.
Using bibtex instead of biber does not help.
Can this behavior be prevented?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@article{personA,
author  = {Person A},
title   = {Did Something},
journal = {C},
volume  = {1},
number  = {1},
year    = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{personA}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What exactly is the privacy concern here? After all, if "Person A" has published a piece, the very act of publishing makes the piece public -- the very opposite of private.

Comment: Looks like `hyperref` uses that as the label. You could try using the solution at [how to customise bib refrence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570357/4301) to use your own label which could be more cryptic, such as `XXXX`.  This would not require any edits to the .bib files.  Or equivalently edit the .bib. file and change `@article{personA` to `@article{XXXX`

Comment: @Mico, maybe the privacy concern is not about the "person A", but about keeping the keys that we define private. e.g. Hypothetically I might want to name a paper `rubbishresearch` in my key, but not disclose this publicly :P

Comment: I agree this is odd and is of concern - why should source code ever unexpectedly appear in the binary of the PDF?

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I have [reported this](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/221).

Comment: @nx105 Which text editor are you using to view the pdf?

Comment: Hyperref has to create a destination and it must have a name. What else can it use apart from the key?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560276/35864

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I think that is the wrong question. I'd more naturally ask: Why do you find it undexpected that the source affects the output?

Comment: @moewe oh I just wanted to write that again ;-)

Comment: DavidCarlisle no I don't find it at all unexpected that source alters output. However finding actual raw code in the binary output is a little surprising. @personA (the actual variable name vs some other tag) serves no purpose in the output. 
It would be like having the source code of my bank's internal database field names and the name of the database they use printed on my bank statement. However in this instance I agree that SOME tag is needed for a link within the file so perhaps it is reasonable that the variable name allocated is used (as opposed to some randomly generated number).

Comment: I think the point here is that most people don't realise (I didn't) that if I label a section title for internal use "tag:Forthatidiotman" it might appear in the output. I have certainly learned something.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and links. Although I would prefer to have a simple <scramble> option for (as it seems) biblatex, I have not found an issue with the scramble-workaround in one of the links. To answer the questions above: 1) Just as I prefer to remove PTEX metadata from the binary, I don't want to share citation keys used; they serve as mental notes and should be private in my opinion. 2) I used Notepad++ as a text editor.