# Footnote identifier available to javascript PDF viewer code

Tags: pdftex, pdf, javascript

I would like to build a javascript browser experience around the PDFs I am creating from LaTex. I'd like to select a footnote and via javascript in the browser I would add comments against that footnote into a database. To do this I'd like to give each footnote a stable identifier in the .tex, compile to PDF, then be able to reference that identifier on the javascript PDF viewer. Essentially I'd like to give a footnote metadata that is passed along to the browser.

The problem I'm having is that all the attempts I've tried (PDF annotations, PDF form elements, PDF comments, etc) doesn't allow me to set an arbitrary identifier that survives the PDF rendering process.

Has anyone done this or have ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but a footnote text is simply a part of the stream, if you don't have a tagged pdf there is nothing no identify it in a special way.

Comment: What do you mean by a tagged PDF?

Comment: a tagged pdf contains additional objects which describe the structure of a document, there a footnote is then e.g. marked as a "/Note" structure. See the PDF reference, https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/pdf/ or look at the documentation of the tagpdf package.  But I don't know if the javascript API can access that info and do with it whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, tagpdf is extremely well thought out. I tried it (using Lua) and unfortunately the tags did not seem to arrive in the PDF bytes.. maybe I'm doing it wrong because it seems tagpdf was to be able to build viewers that can see the structure for a11y purposes. However, I was able to get something working using `\hyperlink` which will do for now. I think `tagpdf` would be a much more appropriate solution if I was able to get it to show the actual tag in the resulting PDF.

Comment: If hyperref is used then footnotes have a named link identifier `#Hfootnote.n` (with `n` the number of the footnote). These identifiers are used to create pdf link annotations, which are represented in a rather readable way in the pdf (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560296/ for an example). You could use the existing identifiers or modify the hyperref code a bit to insert your own.